# How to store a function in hash in typescript?

Tags: typescript, hash

I have a situation where I need to store function as value with key as string in lookup tables. The functions are basically handlers with different names and input params but same return type. When the caller will search for a specific index then it should look for that specific key in the table and it should get the function in return which can be invoked by caller accordingly.

I am new to typescript so not sure how to code for the same. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `obj = {someName: function(){}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare an IHash interface for such a purpose.

```
interface IHash {
    [property: string]: Function
}

const t: IHash = {}

t.name = function () { 
    console.log("the name function invoked")
}

t.name()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myhash: IHash = {};   

myhash["somestring"] = "value"; // set

let value = myhash["somestring"]; // get
```